# In memory load of .NET PE from native process

Tags: c++, .net, c, packer

I did code a PE packer in C++, which does load an executable into his process space, fixes IAT and relocations, then calls the entry point.

My problem is that .NET is not supported: I did search about .NET PE format, and it is just a 32 bit executable with the entry point set to an imported function (_CorExeMain).

If I call it, windows just popups an error that tells me that I have not .NET installed.

I did also read that .NET PE executables have a special COM header in DataDirectory but I don't know how to handle it.

I hope someone could help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: PE is just a container format, like AVI. It makes no guarantees as to what is inside. It merely defines a protocol, where and how information is encoded. The fact that .NET assemblies use the PE file format doesn't mean, that you can simply load it like a native (unmanaged) DLL. You'll have to [host the CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404385.aspx) to activate types in managed assemblies. As an aside, .winmd files also re-use the PE file format (but doesn't contain any code).

Comment: Relevant reading: [Anatomy of a .NET Assembly – The CLR Loader stub](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-the-clr-loader-stub/).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the idea you had does not work as-is for .Net.

Your "packed" executable is just a native executable whose code is an unpacker, and whose data is the compressed real executable. When running, Windows expects and gets native code.

For .Net executables, you must obviously do the same: write a .Net executable whose code is an unpacker, and whose data is the compressed .Net bytecode.